# É possível usar MVC com VB e ASP?

Tags: mvc, asp, visual-basic-6

Existe algum *framework* ou maneira de trabalhar com MVC no ASP + VB?

Me corrijam se estiver errado, mas estou pensando em trabalhar dessa maneira:

```
View -> .ASP
Controller -> .ASP.VB
MODELO/DAO -> .VB
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No ASP provavelmente não. Se for o ASP.NET MVC não tem problema, afinal ele foi feito para isso.

Imagino que vai iniciar um projeto novo, certo? Se não for assim não faz sentido, afinal se vai continuar com o que existe não precisa pensar nisso.

Não há muitos motivos plausíveis para não escolher o ASP.NET Core ou pelo menos o ASP.NET MVC logo (agora, só vale o Core, o MVC valia na época da resposta).

Na verdade há vários motivos para não usar ASP, o principal é que ele não é mais suportado por completo há muito tempo.

Se está preocupado em aprender uma nova linguagem, aprender um *framework* novo dar até mais trabalho. Se optar por VB.NET a distância para o VB é pequena. E as vantagens são enormes, vale o investimento e vai pegar muita coisa pronta. Ainda que depois de dada a resposta sabemos que o VB.NET não terá mais evolução.

Se está usando uma plataforma que não roda .NET Core, pode rodar alguma versão antiga do .NET Framework. Se está em uma plataforma que nem isso é possível, o menor dos seus problemas é escolher um MVC. Seria melhor achar outras soluções já que o projeto é novo e é possível achar algumas viáveis.

Mesmo que dê para simular o ASP não foi concebido parta trabalhar como MVC, haverá muita impedância. Se ainda continuará no ASP use o modelo dele.

Se já usa o ASP.NET MVC então está usando pelo menos o .NET Framework então não tem problema usar o VB.NET.

Talvez esteja achando que ASP é a mesma coisa que ASP.NET e que é a mesma coisa que ASP.NET MVC. Não são, é tudo diferente. Talvez ache que essas tecnologias são linguagens, e não são. Você programará em VB.NET e usará o ASP.NET MVC no projeto.

A forma de organizar o projeto, o que usar em cada ponto aprenderá quando começar.

Sugiro que procure um curso bom onde começa pelo básico já que ainda está dificuldade até com os nomes.

Comment: Sim, é para iniciar novos projetos. Mas no caso não é pra mim, é a linguagem em que a empresa trabalha, e estou procurando alternativas de melhorar os novos projetos

Comment: A melhoria de novos projetos é ir para o .NET Core que é o suportado hoje. ASP fará 20 anos que saiu a última versão. Se a empresa não pode trabalhar com outra coisa, então tem que fazer o arroz com feijão, quanto menos inventar em uma tecnologia tão antiga, melhor.

Comment: @FelipeJunges a pergunta estava confusa, depois eu vi outra pergunta sua. Você diz que é o que a empresa usa. O que a empresa usa. A primeira coisa que tem que saber é o nome correto das coisas, sem isso não poderá tomar decisões, sequer poderá perguntar algo para alguém porque não tem uma informação básica.